# Remove all rows following a row that contains a value

Tags: r

I'm attempting to remove all rows that come after a value (or values) but am running into some trouble.

I want to do the opposite of this: [Filter to remove all rows before the first time a particular value in a specific column appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626654/filter-to-remove-all-rows-before-the-first-time-a-particular-value-in-a-specific)

Using the example dataframe from the above question:

```
(dat<-data.frame(a= c("pete", "mike", "bob", "bart", "bob"), b=c(1,2,3,4,5), c=c("home", "away", "home", "away", "gone")))

         a b    c
    1 pete 1 home
    2 mike 2 away
    3  bob 3 home
    4 bart 4 away
    5  bob 5 gone
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
     a b    c
1 pete 1 home
2 mike 2 away
3  bob 3 home
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
dat %>% slice(which.min(a == "bob") : n())
```

But unlike `which.max` which removed everything before `bob` this doesn't remove anything after it.

Comment: Try `dat %>% slice(1 : which.max(a == "bob"))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
     slice(seq(which.max(a == 'bob')))
```

---

Or with `cumsum`

```
dat %>% 
    filter(lag(cumsum(a == 'bob'), default = 0) < 1)
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
dat[seq_len(match('bob', dat$a)),]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `row_number()` :

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% filter(row_number() <= match('bob', a))

#     a b    c
#1 pete 1 home
#2 mike 2 away
#3  bob 3 home
```