# How to remove all rows following a certain value in a column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

So, as the title says I want to remove all rows within my dataframe that come after a certain value in a certain column, or keep the rows that come before that.

I found this: [Filter to remove all rows before the first time a particular value in a specific column appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626654/filter-to-remove-all-rows-before-the-first-time-a-particular-value-in-a-specific)

But it does not really apply to my condition, since the column I am interested in always starts with an NA and is followed by numbers. I have a lot of files so I am trying to include this into a function that processes these files individually and then binds them all together.

Let's say my dataframe looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("base","A","B","C","D","E"),
                 value = c(NA, 0.2, 0.3, 1, 0.4, 1))
```

I want to delete all rows including and followed by the first `1` in the column `value` so it looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(group = c("base","A","B"),
                 value = c(NA, 0.2, 0.3))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `coalesce` to replace NAs with 0 and apply `cumsum` to keep all values until the first one (included):

```r
library(dplyr)
df |>
  filter(cumsum(coalesce(value, 0) == 1) < 1)

#   group value
# 1  base    NA
# 2     A   0.2
# 3     B   0.3
```

---

Another way would be to use `which.max`; by default, `which.max` picks the first (maximum) index, so this would work:

```r
df[1:which.max(df$value == 1), ]
#or, with head
head(df, which.max(df$value == 1))
#or, using dplyr
slice(df, 1:which.max(value == 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can offer a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(torm = ifelse(value == 1, 1, NA)) %>% 
  fill(torm, .direction ="down") %>% 
  filter(is.na(torm)) %>% 
  select(-torm)

  group value
1  base    NA
2     A   0.2
3     B   0.3
```

Comment: and what if I don't want to keep the NAs?

Comment: @starski You do keep them. See the output 1 row. I filter NAs in a technical temporary column `torm` that I remove by the last line of code